# Slide HTML page in onload (not divs/sections)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, barbajs

I have built a website and now wanting to add a slide on load feature on a few content pages, not the entire site.

I have tried using Barba.js transition but it's not working. I'm not sure if it's conflicted with the jQuery scripts I already have on my website or not.

Is there an easier way for me to create this form of sliding transition between pages not sections or divs just the html pages (index.html > about-us.html and so on...)?

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<img src="ADD YOUR IMAGE" onload="loadImage()" width="100" height="132">

<script>
function loadImage() {
  alert("Image is loaded");
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Try with this example and If you need for this all the pages just add this to the all pages too.